# Scraping Gifs Using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a working code that is able to access Tenor.com, scroll through the website and scrape gifs. But my issue is that it only scrapes and saves upto 24 gifs (no matter how many it scrolls past).

This exact same code works for saving images on other websites (without the same issues presented here).

I've also tried using BeautifulSoup to find all divs with the class "Gif " and then extract the img from each class. But that leads to the exact same result (only 24 gifs being downloaded).

Heres my code and output below. What might the issue be?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyQvs.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests

from urllib.parse import urljoin
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import urllib.request

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
search_url = 'https://tenor.com/'
driver.get(search_url)

time.sleep(5)  # Allow 7 seconds for the web page to open
scroll_pause_time = 2 # You can set your own pause time. My laptop is a bit slow so I use 1 sec
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   #get the screen height of the web
i = 1
start_time = time.time()

while True:
    if time.time() - start_time >= 60:
        break
    # scroll one screen height each time
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))  
    i += 1
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    # update scroll height each time after scrolled, as the scroll height can change after we scrolled the page
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")  
    # Break the loop when the height we need to scroll to is larger than the total scroll height
    if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
        break 

media = []
media_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'Gif ')]//img")
for m in media_elements:
    src = m.get_attribute("src")
    media.append(src)

print("Total Number of Animated GIFs and Videos Stored is", len(media))
print("The Sequence of Pages we Have Scrolled is", i)

for i in range(len(media)): 
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(media[i]),"tenor/media{}.gif".format(i))
```

Comment: It probably unloads the elements as you scroll so it only keeps 1 page's worth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll down with the DevTools opened, you can see that the number of `figure` elements doesn't increase after a certain quantity, i.e. old images are removed from the html as new ones are added.

[image]

So you have to run `.get_attribute("src")` inside the scrolling loop. Also, I suggest you using a `set` instead of a `list` to save the urls, since by running `set.add(url)` the `url` is added only if is not already contained in the `set`.

The code below scrape the images, get the urls and scroll to the last visible image.

```
media = set()
for i in range(6):
    images = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'Gif ')]//img")
    [media.add(img.get_attribute('src')) for img in images]
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});', images[-1])
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This is the correct implementation. Cheers